# using a listbox to display items from a class

Tags: c#, winforms

My program compiles and to me it makes sense.

I want to know how to get 'name' to list in my listbox.

I'm trying to use an array of classes so I can add salesmen. A new class will be created every time a person is to be added.

This way the name is a way of calling all the data in that class.

When I execute the program everything looks like its doing what it's suppose to do but it just lists 'form1' in the list box when i press the list names button

This is what i mean:

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

**SalesmanClass**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
class SalesmanClass
{

    private string name;
    public string cNum;
    public string Email;
    public string address;
    public string gArea;
    public int tSales;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }
```

**Form 1**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 w2;



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (w2 == null)
        {
            w2 = new Form2();
            w2.Show();
        }

    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Object names;
        names = Name;
        listBox1.Items.Add(Name);
    }
}
```

}

**Form 2**

```
//form2
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1

public partial class Form2 : Form
{


    SalesmanClass[] salesman = new SalesmanClass[] { };
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (textBox1.Text.Trim().Length != 0)
        {


            for (int i = 0; i > salesman.Length; i++)
            {

                if (salesman[i] == null)
                {
                    salesman[i].Name = textBox1.Text;
                    break;
                }
            }
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Input a Name");
        }

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this method:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Object names;
    names = Name; // <--- Using this.Name, i.e. Form.Name, NOT SalesmanClass.Name
    listBox1.Items.Add(Name);
}
```

You have accidentally used the `Name` property of the Form itself (which naturally is "form1").

You need to have a `SalesmanClass` object at this point, and use the `Name` property of *that* instead.

You don't currently have a list of salesmen in your Form1, so you will need to add one and use that.

Also, if you have a list or array of `SalesmanClass` objects, you should create a `List<string>` from them and use that to initialise the listbox, something like:

```
SalesmanClass[] salesmen = new SalesmanClass[] {};

// ...

List<string> names = new List<string>();

foreach (var salesman in salesmen)
    names.Add(salesman.Name);

listBox1.Items.AddRange(names);
```

You can do this using Linq too, but I don't want to confuse you by introducing that into the mix!

Comment: ahh okay, how do i reference that same SalesmanClass that i used in form 2?

Comment: @BobJones "How do i reference that same SalesmanClass that i used in form 2": Answer: Well there are many ways, but I would probably add a public method called `SetSalesmen(SalesmanClass[] salesmen)` to both form classes so that the class that creates both forms could pass the list to both the form classes - if you see what I mean!

Comment: In that `SetSalesmen` method, i need to call the string name data that was created in `SalesmenClass` from `Form2`?

Comment: @BobJones You would need to call it from a place that (a) had an instance of the form itself (otherwise you wouldn't be able to call it) and (b) has a reference to the list of salesmen. Somewhere you must be creating form1 and form2, so I think you could call it from there.

Answer (score 1):

In your button2_Click, you have :

```
names = Name;
```

What does this Name belong to ? I suspect it belongs to Form1, that's why it's been displaying "form1". If that's the case, you just need to get your SalesmanClass object and get the Name from it.